# Override theme text color

Tags: material-components

**My problem**

I set my custom theme and it works fine.

But I get black text color on orange( accent) button, but I want to have white color.

**My solution**

In [`@material/theme/_variables.scss`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/packages/mdc-theme/_variables.scss) we have code like this :

```
$mdc-theme-primary: #3f51b5 !default; /* Indigo 500 */
$mdc-theme-accent: #ff4081 !default; /* Pink A200 */
$mdc-theme-background: #fff !default; /* White */

/* Which set of text colors to use for each main theme color (light or dark) */
$mdc-theme-primary-tone: mdc-theme-light-or-dark($mdc-theme-primary);
$mdc-theme-accent-tone: mdc-theme-light-or-dark($mdc-theme-accent);
$mdc-theme-background-tone: mdc-theme-light-or-dark($mdc-theme-background);
```

From the above code, we can see first three params have `!default` which means use this as default , if they are already declared dont override.

For that reason we can specify the custom colors.

But for properties like `$mdc-theme-accent-tone` we are forced to use the calculated values. 
If I change the above code (source code of MDC ) to

```
$mdc-theme-accent-tone: mdc-theme-light-or-dark($mdc-theme-accent) !default;
```

and in my styles

```
$mdc-theme-accent-tone : "light"
```

It works fine. But obviously I can not change the source code. How to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realized this is according to the material design spec. So, expecting a provision to override is wrong. 
But for all practical reasons, to override them do this :

```
@import "@material/theme/mdc-theme";

:root {
    --mdc-theme-text-primary-on-accent: white;
}
```

Remember the override style should be written after importing mdc-theme